# sbt plugins not found: unresolved dendencies

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I created a sbt project called `zim` in Intellj IDEA 2020.3, the sbt version was 1.6.1 and the scala version was 2.13.7.
In `zim/project/build.properties` was:

```
sbt.version = 1.6.1
```

In `zim/project/plugin.sbt` was:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.10.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.scalameta" % "sbt-scalafmt" % "2.4.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-git" % "1.0.2")
```

The first time I build the project, everything is well, dependencies defined in  were downloaded.
But sometimes if I close idea and open it again(mostly from `File > Open recent` because I opened 2 sbt project windows), under the `External Libraries`, nothing were list besides jdk1.8.

[image]

Open the sbt tools window, you'll find refresh button was disabled. I'm curious why the `sbt-and-plugins` dependency was not in the `External Libraries`. I mean, why I cannot find `sbt-and-plugins` dependency in the `External Libraries`.
[image]

And when I run `sbt` command under the project directory or reload project, some errors happened.

```
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.eed3si9n:sbt-buildinfo;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:0.10.0
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: C:\Users\aaa\.ivy2\localcom.eed3si9n\sbt-buildinfo\scala_2.12\sbt_1.0\0.10.0\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/eed3si9n/sbt-buildinfo_2.12_1.0/0.10.0/sbt-buildinfo-0.10.0.pom
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/com/eed3si9n/sbt-buildinfo_2.12_1.0/0.10.0/sbt-buildinfo-0.10.0.pom
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/com/eed3si9n/sbt-buildinfo_2.12_1.0/0.10.0/sbt-buildinfo-0.10.0.pom
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-buildinfo/0.10.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/com.eed3si9n/sbt-buildinfo/0.10.0/ivys/ivy.xml
```

Some info didn't smell like to be consistent with my sbt version and scala version.

```
sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:0.10.0
```

And indeed there's no dependency in above addresses. So why it choose to download from these address? What should I do to download these plugins?

Meanwhile, the import process seems to be forever, in my case, one hour was not enough.
[image]

---

What I've tried:

1. delete `.idea` and reimport project;(sometimes useful but plugins were not found)
2. click `File > Invalid Caches / Restart`;(sometimes useful but plugins were not found)
3. change to scala 2.12.14 according to [official's suggestion](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Configuring-Scala.html)(seems to be no difference with scala 2.13.7)

---

My questions:

1. Why sometimes I reopen the project:

   ```
     dependencies were not found expecially `sbt-and-plugins`?

     idea stuck on importing project?

     refresh button in `sbt tools window` was disabled?
   ```
2. plugins defined in `plugin.sbt` were not downloaded from correct addresses?

Comment: `sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:0.10.0` is absolutely expected and ok. It's the versions used by the plugin, not your project.

Comment: Plugins should be downloaded from a url like `https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases`, maybe check your repositories list?